# Entity Framework query strange parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity framework generates strange params in query. Below is the part of EF generated query.

```
CASE 
    WHEN (
        ( NOT (([Filter2].[C14] = 1) AND ([Filter2].[C14] IS NOT NULL))) AND 
        ( NOT (([Filter2].[C15] = 1) AND ([Filter2].[C15] IS NOT NULL))) AND 
        ( NOT (([Filter2].[C16] = 1) AND ([Filter2].[C16] IS NOT NULL)))) 
        THEN ''2X''
    WHEN (([Filter2].[C14] = 1) AND ([Filter2].[C14] IS NOT NULL)) 
        THEN ''2X0X'' 
    WHEN (([Filter2].[C15] = 1) AND ([Filter2].[C15] IS NOT NULL)) 
        THEN ''2X1X'' 
        ELSE ''2X2X'' 
    END AS [C2],
```

Can't find out what are these 2X, 2X0X, 2X1X, 2X2X. We do not have anything similar in our code base. 
Can anyone suggest what is this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the c# query that represents this one, it might be a joining clause or a SQL specific version product check. Entity does many queries to validate data, most of which you shouldn't care how it works.

Comment: Is there any more SQL in that query, seems like something EF could include to create branching code path in the SQL query.
And I agree that the corresponding C# would be a nice addition.

Comment: These are added discreetly by Entity Framework when it converts your Linq query to a SQL query. Did you get this from the SQL Profiler?

Comment: These are generated when your model is using [TPT](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) or [TPC](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) inheritance strategy.

Comment: @EzLo `DataContext.Set<TEntity>(here goes some app-specific includes and filters).Select(x => new ComplexObject{......}).ToArray()`

Comment: @RobertPerry, yes this is from SQL Profiler

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks! checking those posts!

Comment: Add the C# query...